# Angular 1.6 Data not getting refreshed on subsequent loads

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a problem, there is this typical navigation bar i want to it update every time a different page is loaded. The items on the navbar are working great. It updates when I press and change to another state. The problem is the redirect button on some pages(which should work like shortcut). so say there is btnPg2 on Page1 that should go to page2. On first load it works. The highlighted item on the navigation is correct. However when I return to page1 and try to load page2 again using the btnPg2, The highlighted item on navigation is still on page1. Here's the code, further explanation on bottom.

```
var nav = [{
                urlState: 'page1',
                name: 'Page1',
                icon: '../Images/Icons/1-icon.png',
                hoverIcon: '../Images/Icons/1-icon-active.png',
                path:'page1',
                IsSelected: false
            },
            {
                urlState: 'page2',
                name: 'Page2',
                icon: '../Images/Icons/2-icon.png',
                hoverIcon: '../Images/Icons/2-icon-active.png',
                path: 'page2',
                IsSelected: false
            },
            {
                urlState: 'page3',
                name: 'Page3',
                icon: '../Images/Icons/3-icon.png',
                hoverIcon: '../Images/Icons/3-icon-active.png',
                path: 'page3',
                IsSelected: false
            },
            {
                urlState: 'page4',
                name: 'Page4',
                icon: '../Images/Icons/4-icon.png',
                hoverIcon: '../Images/Icons/4-icon-active.png',
                path: 'page4',
                IsSelected: false
            }
            ];
            $scope.nav = nav;
```

to update highlighted nav item on load there is this code;

```
var updateNav = function (path) {
            var nav = $scope.nav;
            const currentNav = nav.map(currentPage => {
                return {
                    ...currentPage,
                    IsSelected: false
                }
            });
            if (path) {

                var currentActive = currentNav.filter(i => path.indexOf(i.path) > -1)[0];
                if (currentActive)
                    currentActive.IsSelected = true;
                $scope.nav = currentNav;
            }
        }
        $rootScope.updateNav = updateNav;
        $scope.updateNavBar = updateNav;
        updateNav($location.path());
```

now there are buttons on page1 that I want to redirect to other pages much like nav(I know, but humor me). so say, there is btnPg2 to call page2, there is this function;

```
$scope.showPage2 = function () {
            console.log("reached here");
            $state.transitionTo('page2', {}, {
                reload: true,
                inherit: false,
                notify: true
            });
            $rootScope.updateNav('page2');    
        }
```

Again the problem is on subsequent loads, returning to page1 and then clicking on the btnPg2 on page1 again, the state is loaded but it is not reflecting on the navigation. Upon adding console.log and calling it to the page, the 'isSelected' page on console log is correct, say on page 2(so Page2: isSelected = true). but on the page itself, since I have displayed it also to see difference the 'isSelected' is still true on page1. But when I refresh the page, it correctly highlights the current selected page(this case page2). On clicking the items on navbar itself has no problem. Just this redirect/shortcut buttons on some pages

I was wondering if there are any workaround to this? Thanks for taking interest

Comment: You need to use hook for state change, you do not need to call updateNav manually. Rememer that users can also use back-forward buttons.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Thank you for taking time to answer. I'm sorry I'm not familiar with this hooks. What do you mean not needing to call updateNav manually? How does this work exactly? Should I make a new function or replace $rootscope on the showPage2 with this hook function? Is this supported to the version I am currently using? I am using Angular 1.6. Thanks Again